# Prevent direct access to some page in JSF

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-1.2, redirect

I want to restrict direct access to certain page in my application. Those pages can only be accessible if the user is redirected to those pages by the application.

All the redirections are done via `ExternalContext#redirect(url)` method.

User can use back and forward button, also can refresh the page by pressing F5 or via browser's refresh button. What I want is user cannot save, or bookmark URLs of some page, also cannot copy those redistricted URL and paste and go via address bar of the browser.

Followings are the cases:

- Say, I have Page-A and Page-B.
- Redirection is done to Page-B from Page-A.
- User can go back to Page-A and can come again to Page-B by using browser's back and forward button.
- User can refresh Page-B and he/she will stay in Page-B.
- User CANNOT copy the URL of Page-B and access it later time (in new tab or by bookmarking).

Is it feasible? Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do all that from JSF.
Your obvious alternative is to use Javascript.
I never herd a concept of disabling Bookmark option in Browser using Javascript. However you can always disable the address field if you open the page in new Window.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with

JSF Navigation Handler - set a session attribute from some previous page and expire the value after some time with a timer. From the Handler impl check the value of the attribute and restrict access e.g. redirect to some other page in case the value is not present.

You can achieve similar behaviour with web frameworks. Enforcing controlled navigation is a basic feature in most WEB FXs e.g. JBoss Seam conversations or Spring Web Flow controlled navigation implementations.

Comment: I have thought about the timer. But how can I determine it expire time? User can use browser's back and forward button, even refresh the page. If the timer expires before this operations, clearly the custom handler would then redirect the user to other page. Isn't it?

Comment: Right, but your requirement says: "User CANNOT copy the URL of Page-B and access it later time (in new tab or by bookmarking)." - So based on this spec, clearly, you need to define and implement 'later time' somehow... (BTW: you always have HTTP session timeout on the server side, even if you do not define it) In case you only want to check 'URL copy and Bookmarks' that's JavaScript (browser.location attr) but that's easily hackable client side code ...